# Dotnet Core vs DotNetStandard

Tags: .net, .net-core

I already read that dotnetstandard is a subset of functionality.

That much I understood.

dotnet framework full > dotnetstandard > dotnetcore

But how is it possible that e.g. Google API sheet supports dotnetcore with dotnetstandard v1.3?

What do I have to install to allow applications using dotnetstandard 1.3 to run under dotnetcore?

Comment: It might be worth making "what do i have to install to allow applications using dotnetstandard 1.3 run under dotnetcore?" another question.

Answer (score 17):

> Dotnet Core vs DotNetStandard

The two are not "vs" each other. Rather, .NET Core "contains" an implementation of the .NET Standard Library ([as well as extra stuff that is not in .NET Standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44085455/1108891)). Here it is as a Venn diagram.

[image]

> ...how is it possible that e.g. google API sheet support dotnetcore with dotnetstandard v1.3?

It is possible because .NET Core 1.0 supports version 1.3 of the .NET Standard Library.

In [the following table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library), `netcoreapp` is .NET Core, `net` is the .NET Framework, and `netstandard` is the .NET Standard Library. The .NET Standard Library, as you wrote, is a subset of functionality.

**Important:** Each platform advertises the highest version of the .NET Standard Library that it supports.

```
netstandard     1.0     1.1     1.2     1.3     1.4     1.5     1.6     2.0
netcoreapp      →       →       →       →       →       →       1.0     2.0
net             →       4.5     4.5.1   4.6     4.6.1   4.6.2   vNext   4.6.1
```

Here are some examples to check your understanding.

- .NET Core 1.0 supports up to .NET Standard Library 1.6
- .NET Framework 4.6.1 supports up to .NET Standard Library 1.4

.NET Standarded Library 1.3 is supported by...

- .NET Core 1.0 and 2.0
- .NET Framework 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, and vNext

> ...what do i have to install to allow applications using dotnetstandard 1.3 run under dotnetcore?

You have to [install .NET Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core).

Comment: in the other hand if i build a .net standard library 
Can i run it if i have .net framework 4.6.2 or higher without the need for the .net core?!

Comment: @AhmedMohammed Yes. You absolutely can consume a .NET Standard library from within .NET 4.6.2 application. There will in that case be no need for .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this Microsoft Magazine website page made in September 2017 by Immo Landwerth.

[.NET Standard - Demystifying .NET Core and .NET Standard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt842506.aspx)

This page includes the following image and text.

[image]

Here’s how .NET Core and .NET Standard fit into this:

- .NET Core: This is the latest .NET implementation. It’s open source
  and available for multiple OSes. With .NET Core, you can build
  cross-platform console apps and ASP.NET Core Web applications and
  cloud services.
- .NET Standard: This is the set of fundamental APIs (commonly referred
  to as base class library or BCL) that all .NET implementations must
  implement. By targeting .NET Standard, you can build libraries that
  you can share across all your .NET apps, no matter on which .NET
  implementation or OS they run.

**Introduction to .NET Core**

.NET Core is a new cross-platform and fully open source .NET implementation that was forked from .NET Framework and Silverlight. It’s optimized for mobile and server workloads by enabling self-contained XCOPY deployments.

---

**Wrapping Up**

.NET Standard is a specification of APIs that all .NET implementations must provide. It brings consistency to the .NET family and enables you to build libraries you can use from any .NET implementation. It replaces PCLs for building shared components.

.NET Core is an implementation of the .NET Standard that’s optimized for building console applications, Web apps and cloud services using ASP.NET Core. Its SDK comes with a powerful tooling that in addition to Visual Studio development supports a full command line-based development workflow.