# I can use EF Core 2.0 in production applications?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core

[Here in this blog](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/08/09/net-standard-2-0.aspx), they say that .net standard 2.0 it has a consistence state.

[In the official web](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard2.0.md), it doesn't say if .net standard 2.0 is preview or final.

But I guess that .net standard 2.0 is in final version because [EF Core 2.0](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework) final is out, and this uses .net standard 2.0. Perhaps EF Core can be in final version and .net standard 2.0 is still a preview, but I guess it would be odd.

Also, is know that to use .net standard I have to use VS2017 15.3, that is in the 3rd preview version and it says it is not for production applictions.

So my question is, if .net standard 2.0 is consistence version (I don't know if this means final version) and EF Core 2.0 is final version too, but I need VS 2017 15.3 to use it but VS 2017 15.3 is not recommended for production, this means that then is it not a good option to use EF Core 2.0 final in production applications?

Thanks.

Comment: Good question! And strange, except the updated nuget links, I don't see any EF Core 2.0 official announcement (the Roadmap still say *Under Development*), what is in there finally etc.

Comment: One of the features important to me is GroupBy() which is still not available in EF Core 2.0 and has been pushed out to 2.1. See: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2341

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should wait just a few days before the final version .NET core 2 & EF core 2

**EF Core**: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap

> The schedule for EF Core is in-sync with the .NET Core and ASP.NET Core schedule

**NET Core**: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md

**ASP.NET Core** https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap

> Ship Dates
>
> .NET Core 2.0     Q3 2017
>
> .NET Standard 2.0     Q3 2017

**Visual Studio** 2017 Release Rhythm

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-release-rhythm

[image]

**Update 15/08/2017**: .NET core 2.0 + ASP.NET 2.0 + EF 2.0 + VS 2017 15.3 already released.

https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowscmd
https://www.visualstudio.com/

Comment: And do you know when will VS2017 15.3 be released? because if this final version of EF Core 2 and .net core 2 is near but VS2017 is not released and I need the 15.3 version to use them, perhaps what limits is VS2017 and not .net core or EF core.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía Updated. Take a look :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confusing [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) with [.NET Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core). The former [has been finalised](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/24) but the latter is [still in preview](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core).

See also: [.NET Standard vs .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44088694/3603)

Comment: Thanks. When I said that EF Core 2.0 is final, I mean Entityframework Core 2.0, not .net Core. Really I don't know the state of .net Core 2.0. My final goal is to use EF Core 2.0. .net Core is not my objetive.

Comment: But your question relates to .NET Standard, which is just a spec (an "interface" in C# parlance). I'm just trying to point out that your question can't be answered in it's current state. Feel free to clarify and I'll update my answer if I can help.

Comment: Ok. Then I will change my question. What do I need to use EF Core 2.0 and if it is ready to use in production applications?

Comment: That I unfortunately can't help you with, but I'll ping someone who can.

Comment: Essentially your question is "Can EF Core 2.0 practically be used in production considering it only has a .NET Standard 2.0 TFM but the tooling that supports that is still in preview?"

Comment: Yes, it is the question that I wanted to ask. You expose correctly.

Comment: Hang in there for a couple of days