# Easiest way to expose a Framework 4.7.2 library as a Web API

Tags: c#, .net, rest

I have a library created with Visual Studio 2019 and C#, that basically exposes a method that takes a textfile, doing some magic and returning a JSON. Target Framework is 4.7.2, the GUI is WPF. Now I want to expose this method as Web API.

When I started to check the .NET Framework options I totally got confused by Core 3.1, Standard 2.0 and what else. After some readings I guess it would be best to simply wait for .NET 5.0, but I want to do it now. So any suggestions what's the fastest way to get it done? I'm pretty free what to use, but I guess a .NET websomething that can access my library would be the best?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063837/whats-the-difference-between-net-core-net-framework-and-xamarin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42939454/what-is-the-difference-between-net-core-and-net-standard-class-library-project

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44085424/net-standard-vs-net-core/48837359

Comment: @BenVoigt oh my bad! I did a reject and edit on a previous edit, and the rejected edit  put the question title in as their edit comment, and when I made my edit, I thought that was the edit comment so I replaced it with "remove thanks".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, I do believe you are confused about this whole .Net Core and .Net Standard story, please reffer to this [documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support) in order to get some clarification.

As for exposing your method to be consumed as an API, you can do it using C# in the following ways:

- [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio) will give you a serverless way to make your code available.
- [ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) will give you a very MVC-like perspective on offering your code as an API.

In both ways you'll be able to consume your 4.7.2 .Net Framework library.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot to find the right direction (towards Web API). It's up and running :)